# Daemon thread doesn't complete it's execution when we restart zookeeper

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

In our current architecture of the project we are using solr for gathering, storing and indexing documents from different sources and making them searchable in near real-time

Our web applications running on tomcat connecting to solr to create / modify the documents
Solr uses Zookeeper to keep the configuration centralized

There are 5 servers in our cluster where we are running solr

when the zookeeper restarts in one of the server the daemon thread created in the server doesn't complete it's execution due to which
We are getting continuous logs with below exceptions while trying to connect to zookeeper from tomcat instance

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.

which in some time runs out of thread in the server

can someone help me with the below question please ?

why the daemon thread doesn't complete it's execution when we restart zookeeper

Solr Version : 8.5.1
zookeeper version : 3.5.5